# Spring data solr and Solr 6.4.0: default search field

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data-solr

Solr 6.4.0 doesn't allow having default field in schema.xml and throws exception so this line must be removed:

```
<defaultSearchField>product_digest</defaultSearchField>
```

Removing it requires passing it with parameters explicitly.
It's easy to do with solrj4 and ModifiableSolrParams.

But we use the latest release version **spring-data-solr 2.0.6** and I can't figure out how to set it using

> org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.SimpleQuery

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DEPRECATED: The defaultSearchField is commented not deprecated.

**Note**:It is Not recommended by Solr, instead use `df` of requestHandler in `solrconfig.xml`.
 Un-commenting defaultSearchField will be insufficient if your request handler
  in solrconfig.xml defines "df", which takes precedence. That would need to be removed.

Comment: I can't use df in request handler because solrconfig.xml is shared across different cores and in my case I need to pass df for each core individually.

Comment: So from what I see now I don't have another way then create solrconfig for each core separately. Sadly.

Comment: I hope you are using Solr in Cloud mode. but a collection index can be split across different machines, in that case your core is a slice (part of) collection index. single and same solrconfig.xml is used for entire collection. hence you can modify `df` in solrconfig.xml of your collection.